# Inserting a sub-menu that updates records within a main menu

Tags: arrays, c, menu, switch-statement, insert-update

I am trying to make an Insert or Update menu option in my Main Menu, that can update the Quiz Scores (qz1,qz2,qz3) of any student on the array.  However, I am getting stuck at displaying after inserting, and unable to figure out how to do the menu inside the menu.
Here is whare I am stuck at, adding the 'Insert' (or 'Update') Main Menu item:

```
char nm[31];
int qz1,qz2,qz3,sm;
int i,p;
if (isempty()){
    printf("Array is empty.\n");
    system("pause");
}
else{
    p=search(n);
    if (p==-1){
        printf("Not found.\n");
        system("pause");
    }
    else {
        display();
    }
 }
}
```

I can only get to display, but cannot figure out how to display the related quiz scores of the same student, after inputting the student name.

Hope you can help out.  Background is I'm doing self-studying for C Programming.  Started with Global and Local functions calling, then working on Arrays, and most recently, using a Switch/Menu.  Next challenge is to try and update the file by updating the quizzes only without changing the name.

Here is the full program code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 3

char name[MAX][31];
int q1[MAX],q2[MAX],q3[MAX];
int last;

int initialize();
void add(char n[31], int a, int b, int c);
void ins(char n[31]);
void del(char n[31]);
void display();
int search(char n[31]);
int isfull();
int isempty();
int menu();
float average(int a, int b, int c);
void save();
void retrieve();

int main(){
char nm[31];
int qz1,qz2,qz3,m;
initialize();
retrieve();
while(1){
    m=menu();
    switch(m){
    case 1 : system("cls");printf("Insert Mode\n");
             printf("Input Name: ");scanf("%s",nm);
             printf("Input Quiz1: ");scanf("%d",&qz1);
             printf("Input Quiz2: ");scanf("%d",&qz2);
             printf("Input Quiz3: ");scanf("%d",&qz3);
             add(nm,qz1,qz2,qz3);break;
    case 2 : system("cls");printf("Insert Mode\n");
             printf("Input Name: ");scanf("%s",nm);ins(nm);break;
    case 3 : system("cls");printf("Delete Mode\n");
             printf("Input Name: ");scanf("%s",nm);del(nm);break;
    case 4 : display();break;
    case 5 : save();printf("File Saved.\n");system("pause");exit(0);
    default: printf("Please select an option between 1-5 only\n");system("pause");

    }

}

return 0;
}
int initialize(){
  last = -1;
}
void add(char n[31], int a, int b, int c){
if (isfull()){
    printf("Array is full!.\n");
    system("pause");
}
else{
    last = last+1;
    strcpy(name[last],n);
    q1[last]=a;
    q2[last]=b;
    q3[last]=c;
}
}

void ins(char n[31]){
char nm[31];
int qz1,qz2,qz3,sm;
int i,p;
if (isempty()){
    printf("Array is empty.\n");
    system("pause");
}
else{
    p=search(n);
    if (p==-1){
        printf("Not found.\n");
        system("pause");
    }
    else {
        display();
    }
 }
}

void del(char n[31]){
int i,p;
if (isempty()){
    printf("Array is empty.\n");
    system("pause");
}
else{
    p=search(n);
    if (p==-1){
        printf("Not found.\n");
        system("pause");
    }
    else {
        for (i=p;i<last;i++){
            strcpy(name[i],name[i+1]);
            q1[i]=q1[i+1];
            q2[i]=q2[i+1];
            q3[i]=q3[i+1];
        }
        last--;
    }
 }
}


int search(char n[31]){
int i;
for (i=0;i<=last;i++)
    if (strcmp(name[i],n)==0)
        return i;
return -1;
}
void display(){
int i;
float av;
system("cls");
printf("No.\tStudent\tQuiz1\tQuiz2\tQuiz3\tAverage\tRemarks\n");
for(i=0;i<=last;i++){
    av = average(q1[i],q2[i],q3[i]);
    printf("%d.)\t%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%6.2f\t%s\n",i+1,name[i],q1[i],q2[i],q3[i],av, av>=75.0 ? "Passed":"Failed");
}
system("pause");
}
int menu(){
int op;
system("cls");
printf("Menu\n");
printf("1.) Add Student record\n");
printf("2.) Insert Student record\n");
printf("3.) Delete Student record\n");
printf("4.) Display\n");
printf("5.) Exit\n");
printf("Select(1-5): ");
scanf("%d",&op);
return(op);
}
int isfull(){
return(last==MAX-1);
}
int isempty(){
if (last==-1)
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
}

float average(int a, int b, int c){
return((a+b+c)/3.0);
}
/*saving function*/
void save(){
FILE *fp;
int i;
fp = fopen("Update.dbf","w+");
if (fp==NULL){
    printf("Error - File Not Found.\n");
    system("pause");
}
else{
    for (i=0;i<last;i++)
        fprintf(fp,"%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",name[i],q1[i],q2[i],q3[i]);
}
fclose(fp);
}

void retrieve(){
FILE *fp;
int i;
char n[31];
int qz1,qz2,qz3;
fp = fopen("Update.dbf","r+");
if (fp==NULL){
    printf("Error - File Not Found.\n");
    system("pause");
}
else {
    while(!feof(fp)){
        fscanf(fp,"%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",n,&qz1,&qz2,&qz3);
        add(n,qz1,qz2,qz3);
    }
}
fclose(fp);
}
```